Did most Alawites support Assad?
Before the fall of the regime, Alawites were widely considered to be Assad's main base of support within Syria. But how many of them actually supported him? Was it the majority?

Polling is essentially non-existent, but would this be surprising? Assad stayed in power during a 10 year civil war, he wasn't completely without support. If you had asked this question a month ago, many people would say they supported him.  Of course if you ask anyone in Syria now they'll tell you that they had always been opposed to Assad.

You may see some very weird beliefs.  For example, in 2003-2004 it was common to see press articles claiming that some/many of Sunni Iraqis believed they represented 50% of Iraqis (they're at 30).  To leverage a minority's support a clever dictator would also instill a belief that their fate depends on him.

long read:  2016 Primer on the Alawites in Syria - Foreign Policy Research Institute

I'm not sure how you define and measure "support" in an ethnically-divided autocracy during a civil war. The historical scope of the question also isn't clear as the two Assads together ruled for half a century.
It is clear that "large parts of the informal power structure around" the Assads were Alawites (EUAA 2020). It is also notable that at one point over 80% of the Alawite community worked for the state (Balanche 2015). Obviously few if any of those people were openly expressing opposition to the regime. Sunni and Kurdish opponents of the regime have sometimes targeted Alawites as such, which may have tended to push them towards the regime for protection. Nonetheless some "Alawite opposition activists were targeted by the government forces for arbitrary arrest, torture, detention and killing (EUAA 2020)."
It is probably safe to say that Alawites who openly opposed Assad were never anything close to a majority, if that counts as support.
